# How to use the instanceof to determine if a class' left and right objects belongs to another class

Tags: java

So I have this prompt:

> Call a static method to return the count of how many elements in the array of ArithExpression's are SIMPLE binary expressions (are ArithBinaryExpression objects in which the leftExpression and rightExpression variables refer to ArithValue's)—you MUST usetheinstanceofoperatorhere

What I'm having a hard time understanding is, how do I implement the instanceof to determine left and right expression objects of a class is an instanceof another class

This is my code of the classes required:

```
public interface ArithExpression {
    public abstract double result();
}
```

---

```
public class ArithValue implements ArithExpression {
private double doubValue;

ArithValue(double dVal) {
    this.doubValue = dVal;
}

public double result() {
    return doubValue;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(doubValue);
}

}
```

---

```
public abstract class ArithBinaryExpression implements ArithExpression {
protected static ArithExpression leftExpression;
protected static ArithExpression rightExpression;

// constructor
public ArithBinaryExpression(ArithExpression left, ArithExpression right) {
    if (left == null) {
        leftExpression = new ArithValue(0);
    }
    else 
    leftExpression = left;

    if (right == null) {
        rightExpression = new ArithValue(0);
    }
    else
    rightExpression = right;


}
// end constructor

// accessors
public ArithExpression getLeftExpression() {
    return leftExpression;
}

public ArithExpression getRightExpression() {
    return rightExpression;
}
```

UPDATE #2: 
This is the isSimple() method:

```
public boolean isSimple() {
    boolean isSimple = false;
    if (leftExpression instanceof ArithValue && rightExpression instanceof ArithValue) {
        isSimple = true;
    }
    return isSimple;
}
```

This is the iteration through the ArithExpression array implementation:

```
    public static int simpleBinary(ArithExpression[]arithExpressions) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arithExpressions.length; i++)
    {
        if(arithExpressions[i].isSimple() == true) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I get an error saying that the method isSimple() is undefined for the type ArithExpression.

Comment: You don't need to determine the "left and right objects" for each element, just if each element is a binary arithmetic object.

Comment: Why don't you just check the values to be instanceof `ArithValue`, e.g. `return leftExpression instanceof ArithValue && rightExpression instanceof ArithValue`. The real obstacle is to collect all binary expression, e.g. with depth first traversal of the expression graph/tree.

Comment: So how would I implement it that way ?

Comment: From your problem description I read that you want to count all simple binary expressions, right? Then first try to collect all binary expressions? Can you do this? And then filter this collection to contain only simple binary expression by checking left and right operator. Which of these subtasks is your first problem?

Comment: I think what I'm having the most trouble with is checking for the left and right operators in the operation. How would I do that?

Comment: write a method `boolean isSimple()` just containing the code I posted in the comment as body.

Comment: @CoronA I edited the post and added in the bit that I wrote so far. But the compiler provides an error stating: Multiple markers at this line
 - Incompatible conditional operand types ArithBinaryExpression and 
  ArithValue
 - Incompatible conditional operand types ArithBinaryExpression and 
  ArithValue

Comment: do it the way i described it. No static method, no additional variables. Just write the method into the body of the class `ArithBinaryExpression`. The static method is the second step: Try to iterate above the `arithExpressions` array and call `isSimple` on each binary expression. Update your problem description if you get stuck on this task.

Comment: @CoronA I just added a second update! I now get an error saying that the method isSimple() is undefined for the ArithExpression type

Comment: Yes - your interface does not define such a method. You can add an interface method (forcing you to add this method to avery implementing class), or you check/cast your arithmetic expression to `ArithmeticBinaryExpression`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can you instanceof as under to determine the class of the object as under

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass s = new SuperClass();
    Child1 c = new Child1();
    Child2 cc = new Child2();

    checkInstance(s);
    checkInstance(c);
    checkInstance(cc);
}

private static void checkInstance(SuperClass c) {
    if(c instanceof SuperClass){
        System.out.println(" c Instance of superclass");
    }
    if(c instanceof Child1){
        System.out.println(" c Instance of Child1");
    }
    if(c instanceof Child2){
        System.out.println(" c Instance of Child1");
    }
}
```

This will help you pin point the exact class instance.
Please note that Child1 and Child2 extends SuperClass.

Code below is to keep a count of number of instances of each class

```
static int CHILD_1_COUNTER = 0;
static int CHILD_2_COUNTER = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass s = new SuperClass();
    Child1 c1 = new Child1();
    Child2 c2 = new Child2();
    Child2 c3 = new Child2();
    Child2 c4 = new Child2();
    List<SuperClass> list = new ArrayList<SuperClass>();
    list.add(s);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c4);

    checkInstance(list);

    System.out.println("No. of Child1 instances" + CHILD_1_COUNTER);
    System.out.println("No. of Child2 instances" + CHILD_2_COUNTER);

}

private static void checkInstance(List<SuperClass> list) {
    list.forEach(element ->{
        if(element instanceof Child1)
            CHILD_1_COUNTER++;
        if(element instanceof Child2)
            CHILD_2_COUNTER++;
    });

}
```

Request you to accept the answer if it solves your problem :)